# Does Cloudinary prevent arbitrary file uploads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cloudinary

What does @cloudinary do to prevent malicious users from arbitrary file uploads through the client side image API? Is there any configuration that is required to ensure that arbitrary file uploads are blocked?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cloudinary's uploader, you can specify the allowed file types in `upload()`:

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload('image.jpg', allowed_formats: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'])
```

If you use [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), then you can whitelist the file types that are allowed. For example:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Comment: What about client side uploads?

Comment: You can use `acceptFileTypes`, here is an example: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js#client-side-image-resizing-before-upload

Comment: Thanks! But I still need to do something to prevent users who change this property in their browser... is there a Cloudinary side (server-side) setting that makes sure the endpoint only accepts images?

Comment: I don't think there is a Cloudinary setting for that. But why is this is a problem? If the file is not an image, Cloudinary will return an error on upload. If the file is an image, you can convert it to any format: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#format_conversion

Answer (score 0):

You can set an upload preset and set it as your default upload preset. This can be defined from within your upload settings page:
https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/upload

The upload preset can include lots of upload related parameters, such as allowed formats, incoming transformations, eager transformations and much more.

That way, no matter if the user changed your client-side code, only allowed formats defined in your upload presets will be allowed for upload.